# Oracle - Adding columns to a table takes forever

Tags: oracle, alter-table

I need to add two DATE columns to an already existing table. But it takes very long and I have to kill the process. What is strange is I was able to add those columns to the other tables in the same database momentarily. Most of those tables are larger than the one I'm having trouble with both data and column-count-wise. What do I have to do to be able to add those new columns?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Are you adding a default value or are you just adding the column?  How big is the table?  What is "very long"?  Hours?  Days?

Comment: It's Oracle 10g. Yes I am adding SYSDATE as a default to one of those columns. The table's got 3.923.327 records with 11 columns. It took 6+ minutes  and I just interrupted the process.

Comment: How many rows are in that table?

Comment: IMO 6 minutes is not a "long time". Six minutes is "longer than I'd like but what the hey it's nearly 4 million records I'll sit here a bit and let it grind hey let's check statistics on that and see what's going on ho-hum glad I get paid for this hmmm what's in the junk machine whoops time for a quick trip down the hall dang is this thing still going hey how'd the team do yesterday what's up with what's-her-name in HR heard she's splitsville with the old man sure I've got time for a question what a maroon dang is...hey it's done!". That's about how long six minutes is. :-)

Comment: Yeah, but how do you know how long it will take? I kille dthe process at the sixth minute. It would probably take more tha half an hour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here's how I solved the problem. Before, I was specifying a default value for the columns right at the moment of adding them. But then I first added the columns with no default values. After columns got added I specified the default value and it executed immediately with no more waiting. Thank you very much @Justin Cave for your hint about Default value. That was the key point.

I have no doubt that it's related with the fact that when specifying default value at the time of adding column that default value is written to all the records inserted earlier.So if there are 5 million records in the table, that table will be updated to set default value for the newly added column for all the rows. Updating 5 million records is expensive as one might guess. But if default value is set after adding a column then the value of that new column in the rows inserted earlier will be NULL, so no update will take place.

Comment: @Jens - that's because adding a default value later on does not affect the existing rows, whereas when adding a new column, the default value must be set on each row - unless the default is NULL, in which case Oracle doesn't have to visit the existing rows.

Comment: It should be noted that in Oracle 11g, adding a column with a default value no longer has this problem (Oracle doesn't update all the existing rows, but merely updates the metadata).

Comment: I am facing a similar problem in PostgreSQL 9.2. I am adding a new column with character varying(50) without any defaults. My table contains about 1 million records but the query is executing for the last 1 hour and is still on.. Please help.

This is the query that I have given:

ALTER TABLE ccdb.consumer_index_details ADD COLUMN rapdrp_pole_code character varying(50);

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this problem when adding a varchar2(4000) column **with no default value** one a 61K row table in Oracle 11g. After 30 minutes the column was still not added.

I tried to abort the operation, and retried it, but it still didn't finish.

What worked:
I tried adding a number column instead, that took a split second. Dropped it.
Then i tried adding a varchar2(1) column, that took a split second. Dropped it.
Then i tried adding a varchar2(4000) column again, and it only took a split second.

Silly "workaround", but maybe this also works for anyone else facing this problem.